# Solving an Olympiad type problem with Lifting the Exponent Lemma

Tags: elementary-number-theory, contest-math, divisibility

I've just partially solved an Olympiad type problem using LTE and would like some feedback on how to find other values of $n$ that satisfy the constraints.

Problem: find $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $n^{2} | 2^{n}+1$

1. $V_{3}(2^{n}+1)=V_{3}(3)+V_{3}(n)$ $(V_{3}(3)=1)$
2. $V_{3}(2^{n}+1) \geq V_{3}(n^2)$  (because of divisibility)
3. $V_{3}(n^2) = 2*V_{3}(n)$
4. $2*(V_{3}(2^{n}+1) - 1) = V_{3}(n^2)$
5. $V_{3}(2^{n}+1) \geq 2*(V_{3}(2^{n}+1) - 1)$
6. $x=V_{3}(2^{n}+1) \rightarrow x \geq 2x -2$
7. Solutions: $n=1$ $n=3$

What about other values of $n$ that are multiples of $3$?

Comment: well ... for  n=3k, k can't be divisible by 3 ...

Comment: https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h60740p366466